# "IntentReceiver cannot be resolved to a type". Why?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

I'm building a small app that requieres the IntentReceiver.

Actually, I am a newb at Android development and am doing the switch after iOS development.
I have the following code:

```
package com.TheIntent;

import android.content.*; //I added this AFTER I got the error message

public class ReceiveSMS extends IntentReceiver {

}
```

But is giving me the error I put in the title. I'm following the code as it is written in the book I'm reading about Android development, and after googling for a while I found I have to include android.content.IntentReceiver. But like you can see, it's not working.

I am working with the SDK 2.3.3.

Thanks for any help you may provide!

Comment: Try to compile , may be IDE shows up incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/deb0171a847fb933/f340d4f1b06805a2?show_docid=f340d4f1b06805a2) - basically `IntentReceiver` has been removed (a long time ago), and replaced with [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

(If you're following a tutorial or book which refers to `IntentReceiver`, it sounds like you may want to get a more recent one.)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Dang. It's being hard to find an updated Android Development book... Thanks a lot for your answer. Just out of curiosity, why did they do this change?

Comment: @Sergio: No idea, I'm afraid - I've never done any Android development myself. Although I was briefly on the Android team, I was miles away from the SDK - please don't take anything about this answer to be "from a Google spokesman" or anything like that ;)